# url_for: how to look into another folder other than static

Tags: python, flask

I have a file test.css in a folder called css. I want to create url for this file. I know that I can use `url_for` like

```
url_for('static', filename="test.css")
```

to create url like `static/test.css` but I am not able to use like

```
url_for('css', filename="test.css")
```

to create the url that I am interested in `css/test.css`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`static` just endpoint, see [route](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.12.2/flask/app.py#L539) and [view](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.12.2/flask/helpers.py#L916). So you can create own endpoints:

```
app.add_url_rule('/css/<path:filename>', endpoint='css',
                 view_func=app.send_static_file)
```

Comment: This works, just make sure that the production web server is also set up to serve the `/css` directory, just like you would have it serve the `/static` directory.

Comment: I think, the links no more provides the intended lines. @tbicr

Comment: It does generate the correct url but when I run the app, it can't find the files. For example url_for('css', filename="test.css") generates "/css/test.css" which is correct but in console output it shows that the app can't find "/css/test.css". What can be the issue?